# abstract classes with generics in c++ / Qt

Tags: c++, qt, generics, abstract-class

When I run the following code and press the enter button, I get a Segmentation Fault.
I've searched everywhere on the internet, but I can't find the problem. I'm quite new to C++/Qt.

The base class:
stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

template <class T> class stack
{
public:
    stack();
    virtual T pop() = 0;
    virtual void push(T i) = 0;
};

#endif // STACK_H
```

stack.cpp

```
#include "stack.h"

template<class T> stack<T>::stack()
{
}
```

arraystack.h

```
#ifndef ARRAYSTACK_H
#define ARRAYSTACK_H

#include "stack.h"

template <class T> class arraystack : public stack<T>
{
public:
    arraystack();
    T pop();
    void push(T i);
};

#endif // ARRAYSTACK_H
```

arraystack.cpp

```
#include "arraystack.h"
#include <QDebug>

template<class T> arraystack<T>::arraystack()
{
}

template<class T> T arraystack<T>::pop(){
    qDebug() << "popping bad";
}

template<class T> void arraystack<T>::push(T i){
    qDebug() << "pushing shit";
}
```

The part that calls the `pop`-Function:
calculator.h

```
// ...
private:
    Ui::calculator *ui;
    arraystack<int> *h;
    bool integer;
// ...
```

calculator.cpp

```
// ...    
void calculator::on_b_enter_clicked()
    {
        h->pop();
    }
// ...
```

Error:
**The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System

Signal name: SIGSEGV

Signal meaning: Segmentation Fault**

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles, since you've defined the headers in source files. But if it somehow does, then perhaps you haven't initialised `h` properly. Or possibly that you've corrupted its value somehow. Use your debugger to check that it points to a valid object.

Comment: Could you show the code part, where you actually create the objects (using `new` and such)?

Comment: (Sorry, I meant "defined the **templates** in source files". Too late to correct it now.)

Comment: @MatthiasB I've try'd using the new keyword.. but it gave the error: undefined reference to 'arraystack<int>::arraystack()`. Also @mike, where do you see that i defined the headers in the source files?

Comment: ok iv'e try'd to do the template defining in the header files.. no success.. could you give the correct example in an answer?

Comment: Could you please include a [correct and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in your question.

Comment: Why is `h` an `arraystack<int> *`? There's no point dynamically allocating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

A.h

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(){}

    virtual void f1() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class B: public A<T>
{
public:
    B(){}

    void f1(){}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main ()
{
    A<int> *a = new B<int>();

    a->f1();
}
```

Compiles and works, because all template functions are defined in header file. If you want to split the declaration and the definition, you can use one of these methods:

- Include the cpp file at the bottom of your header file
- Include the cpp file in main.cpp

Comment: why A<int> *a = new B<int>(); ? is B<int> *a = new B<int>(); wrong?

Comment: no, A is a Base class of B so you can create a B instance and assign it to a A pointer. Then you can use the A interface